# ANTLR 4: How get correct order arguments in Listeners

Tags: listener, antlr4

In my grammar, function arguments are not mandatory, for example:

foo (param1,,, param4) / / It's valid

Considering this grammar:

```
expressionlist
     :  COMMA* expression?
     (COMMA expression?) *
     ;
```

In my listerner the context array has only two elements.

```
@ Override public void exitExpressionList (ExpressionListContext ctx) {
ctx.expression (0). getText () / / Retuns "param1"
ctx.expression (1). getText () / / Retuns "param4"
}
```

I would like to know that I have four arguments, and the order they are:

```
ctx MyArryList ... (0) / / Retuns "param1"
ctx MyArryList ... (1) / / EMPTY 
ctx MyArryList ... (2) / / EMPTY 
ctx MyArryList ... (3) / / Retuns "param4"
```

It is possible to add a context white, when I find a COMMA?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can track this by making sure the omitted arguments still appear in the parse tree. Note that you *must* use `COMMA` and *not* `COMMA*` in the rule if you want this to work.

```
expressionList
  : (COMMA optionalExpression)*
  ;

optionalExpression
  : expression?
  ;
```

Then in your visitor you can use the following:

```
public void exitExpressionList(ExpressionListContext ctx) {
  ExpressionContext firstArgument = ctx.optionalExpression(0).expression();
  boolean omittedFirst = firstArgument == null;
}
```

Comment: It's worked!
Thank you,
Just needed to change this in the grammar to accept the first argument with a valid expression:

`expressionList
    : optionalExpression (COMMA optionalExpression)*
  ;

optionalExpression
  : expression?
  ;
`

Thank a Lot!